# Deferred Deep Link with Facebook SDK in Unity

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine

I have researched all internet, but still didn't find a solution (I know, that same question is exist on StackOverFlow, but it's too old, and haven't answered yet)

So the task is simple : enable deep linking in Android application. 
When i do it in Android Studio, by writing on java it's okay. I can do it.

But, when using Unity i have a big problems, what i did:

In one of the scripts of my scene i make it:

```
FB.Mobile.FetchDeferredAppLinkData(result =>
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Url)
                {
                    //something to-do
                }
                //something to-do #2
            });
```

I tried rly a lot, was trying to start examples of Facebook SDK (but they don't works), a added AppLink in Facebook Setting page (in Unity i mean), was trying to move this code (and this code without any if and else (just do simple methods)), but nothing happens, when app starts it's like always time black screen.

I know, that i'm in correct way added SDK, because i can track this app on my Facebook page.

So, the question is next : How to enable deferred deep linking in Android application using Unity and Facebook SDK. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Install FacebookSDK
2. Include namespace (using Facebook.Unity;)
3. And in the start add this code

   ```
        if (FB.IsInitialized)
        {
            FB.ActivateApp();
        }
        else
        {

            FB.Init(() =>
            {
                FB.ActivateApp();
                FB.Mobile.FetchDeferredAppLinkData(x =>
                {
                    deep = x.TargetUrl;
                });
            });
        }
   ```